# Sorting integers into a group of arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have a collection of data returned from a class as below

```
item[0].value, item[1].value, item[2].value
```

I want to put the `value` into three separate arrays based on the value.

**example:**

```
item[0].value = red
item[1].value = blue
item[2].value = green
item[3].value = red
item[4].value = red
item[5].value = blue

Array red = { item[0], item[3], item[4] }
Array blue = { item[1], item[5] }
Array green = { item[2] }
```

How do I do this in C#?

**EDITED *(I'm new in C# so I'm really not sure how to represent them, Sorry guys)***

the correct collection I receive should be like below

```
item.value[0].color = red
item.value[0].color = blue
item.value[0].color = green
item.value[0].color = red
item.value[0].color = red
item.value[0].color = blue
```

I want to group the above `item.value[x]` based on its `color` value.

**Like:**

```
Group Red will have item.value[0], item.value[3], item.value[4]
Group blue will have item.value[1], item.value[5]
```

and so on.

**Experiment:**

```
int[] colors = { item.value[0].value, item.value[1].value, item.value[2].value };

int[] Red = colors.Where(c => c == "Red").ToArray();
```

This returns a `Red Array` but not the `item.value[0]` which returned Red. I want the Red Array to have the respective `item.value[x]` which had Red in them.

Comment: Do you know beforehand what all possible values could be? is it always one of these three? are the possibilities limited or unlimited? what is the maximum possible size of the `item` array? are the values really strings or they are something else (integers?) and you are using a analogy to red/green/blue?

Comment: what is the data type for red blue and green? what has this got to do with integers as mentioned in your question?

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer its mostly int for red i get 1, 2 for green and so on. I just put the color val here for easy understanding. Sorry if I confused you. :)

Comment: @inquisitive actually yes. int the item.value[x], x is always 0 - 9 and color is always 12 or less colors

Comment: what is the data-type (class) of `item`? what is it for the `value`. you can see it by hovering your mouse over it.

Comment: its int it seems. i get it like this, int colorVal = item.value[0].value; and colorVal is 1 or 3 or 2 or something like that

Comment: I did something like int[] color = { item.value[0].value, item.value[1].value, item.value[2].value, item.value[3].value }; and int[] Red = item.Where(c => c == "1").ToArray(); this creates the Red Array with Values, but i how do i get the item.value[x] from which the color returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong in a couple of places. You don't need the `.Value` to assign to an array.. and you forgot the quotations around the strings.

Do it like this.

```
        string[] item = new string[6];
        item[0] = "red";
        item[1] = "blue";
        item[2]= "green";
        item[3] = "red";
        item[4]= "red";
        item[5] = "blue";
```

and you can create new arrays by using linq

```
 string[] redArray = item.Where(c => c == "red").ToArray();
```

If `item` is not a string and has a `.Value` property then your linq would be

```
item[] redArray = item.Where(c => c.Value == "red").ToArray();
```

---

Based on your experiment consider this

```
int[] colors = { item.value[0], item.value[1], item.value[2] };

var Red = colors.Where(c => c.value == "Red").ToArray();
```

Where `Red` is an array of your original datatype rather than just an array of the colour red.

Comment: Hi, Well, I'm very new to C#, thus let me explain my situation a bit further. I get a collection of a sort from a class which returns something like item.value[1].color, item.value[2].color in this i want to group item.value[0] 's based on the item.value[x].color value. I'm sorry if i confused you :)

Comment: Edited the original question as you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

LINQ should do the trick:

```
var groups = item.GroupBy(x => x).Select(color => color.ToList()).ToList();
```

It will return the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to do this pretty easily

```
List<Color> colors = new List<Color>{Color.Red, Color.Red, Color.Blue, Colour.Green};
Color[] red = colors.Where(c => c == Color.Red).ToArray();
Color[] blue = colors.Where(c => c == Color.Blue).ToArray();
Color[] green = colors.Where(c => c == Color.Green).ToArray();
```

Even if your data structure is an `Array`, the Linq will still be the same.

Here is the MSDN documention on the `Where()`

[Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just define a enum for colors and using linq query simply you can do that.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Color> item = new List<Color>();

            item.Add(Color.blue);
            item.Add(Color.red);
            item.Add(Color.blue);
            item.Add(Color.red);
            item.Add(Color.red);
            item.Add(Color.green);

            List<Color> red = item.Where(x => x.Equals(Color.red)).ToList();
            List<Color> blue = item.Where(x => x.Equals(Color.blue)).ToList();
            List<Color> green = item.Where(x => x.Equals(Color.green)).ToList();
        }
        enum Color
        {
           red,
           blue,
           green
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in your comments that there could be only 10 items, and each `item`'s `value` would lie between `[0-11] inclusive`. Also you say that the `color` thing is actually a misdirection and they are actually `integers` not physical colors.

there being only 10 items to analyze and classify, it doesnt really matter which way you go. even 10 `if-elseif-else` ladder would perform well enough, but may not *look* beautiful though.

for larger numbers of elements in the `item` array, and for sheer academic interest, the optimal approach here is something called [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). please look it up. the following pseudocode will help you.

```
INPUT:    items   AS ARRAY[9]      

DECLARE:  colors  AS ARRAY[12]       //will hold final results for each color

FOR(i = 0 UPTO 11)
    colors[i] = NEW ARRAYLIST        //will hold the final result for color no. i

FOR(j = 0 UPTO items.length)
    itm = items[j]
    colr = itm.value                 //take the color, should be between 0-11
    bucket = colors[colr]            //bucket is the arraylist coresponding to color
    bucket.add(itm)                  //store the item in its color's bucket
```

after the loop finishes, you will get your items in `colors` array. do note that each cell of the array is an `ArrayList` in itself. hence it will contain a sequence of `items`.

```
colors[0]  = { item[0], item[6], ...}
colors[1]  = { item[4], item[9], ...}
colors[2]  = { item[7], ...}
  ...
  ...
colors[11] = {...}
```

try to translate it in C#. ask if you fail.